# linear mixed effect model cross validated

Tags: r, regression, effects

Hi if I have lots of response variables that I want to use in a linear mixed effect model, do I have to run those separately by each response variable or is there a different model I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably edit your question to give more context and a minimal reproducible example. But if by response variable you mean dependent variables, yes you need to run separate linear mixed models for each response/dependent variable. This is not so much a property of mixed models - you would need to do this also with single-level regressions. Whether to use a mixed model or not depends on whether your data is hierarchical (e.g. several observations per participant or participants nested within different schools).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a lot of explanatory variables as well? I was thinking if you could eventually do some multivariate analysis (PCA) with all the dependent variables and then check if there is any pattern in clustering?

This could also help you check which variables contribute more to your clustering.